# Add toolbar in certain fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a main activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

This activity just has a framelayout and uses this layout to add, replace, and delete fragments.

I have 2 fragments:

- LoginFragment  (constraintLayout)

  ```
  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="#4CF">

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/button2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Go to Register"
      android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
      android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
      app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.500" />
  ```

  - RegisterFragment  (constraintLayout)

  ```
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="56dp"
      android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
      android:elevation="4dp"
      android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
      app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
      tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
      android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
      android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Welcome to the Register fragment"
      tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="205dp"
      tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="62dp" />
  ```

The login fragment shows up first. This should have no actionbar. There is a button in this fragment which will replace this login fragment with the register fragment. In this fragment I want the actionbar to show up so that it can have the back arrow in the actionbar to go back to the login view. I have no idea though where to place the toolbar widget in the code? I have tried to set it in the register fragment, but it kept displaying oddly.

Comment: `I have no idea though where to place the actionbar?` What do you expect us to suggest? "Put it in top and make it's height equal dimen/actionBarHeight"?

Comment: @azizbekian What I mean is where to put the toolbar code so that in the registration fragment there is a toolbar visible.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. In the activity I just wrap everything in a linear layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then in the fragments themselves I have a method to hide/show the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Toobar` from your `RegisterFragment` and place it to your `activity_main.xml` file.

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Show and hide `Toolbar` programmatically from your fragment's `OnCreate()` method. Use `YOUR_ActionBar.show()` to show `Actionbar` and `YOUR_ActionBar.hide()` to hide `Actionbar`.

**LoginFragment**

```
// ActionBar
ActionBar mActionBar;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // ActionBar
    mActionBar = ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    mActionBar.hide();

}
```

**RegisterFragment**

```
// ActionBar
ActionBar mActionBar;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // ActionBar
    mActionBar = ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    mActionBar.show();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

just make Layout

toolbar.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorAccent"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
```

wherever u need toolbar just include the Layout like

```
<include layout="@layout/toolbar.xml">
```